# RequiredFieldValidator only works for one validation

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, validation, gridview

I have a web application written in VS2010.
I have a GridView in which I want to add 2 different validations to a field in edit mode.  One validation is that it is a required field.  The other validation is a max. length of 80 characters.
Below is my HTML:

```
<asp:GridView ID="UserInfoGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        Caption="User Information" CaptionAlign="Top" CssClass="grid" HorizontalAlign="Left" 
        PageSize="1" Width="400px" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" Height="60px"
        OnRowCancelingEdit="UserInfoGridView_RowCancelingEdit" 
        OnRowEditing="UserInfoGridView_RowEditing" 
        OnRowUpdating="UserInfoGridView_RowUpdating">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="uigvTxtBoxName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserName") %>'></asp:TextBox>   
                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldEditName" ControlToValidate="uigvTxtBoxName" runat="server"
                        ErrorMessage="Required field." ValidationGroup="EditUserNameValidation" Display="Dynamic" 
                        CssClass="message-error">
                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>                   
                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="MaxValEditName" ControlToValidate="uigvTxtBoxName" runat="server"
                        ErrorMessage="Maximum length is 80." ValidationGroup="EditUserNameValidation" Display="Dynamic" 
                        CssClass="message-error" ValidationExpression="^.{1,80}$">
                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="uigvLblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email Address" ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="uigvTxtBoxEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserEmail") %>'></asp:TextBox>      
                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldEditEmail" ControlToValidate="uigvTxtBoxEmail" runat="server"
                        ErrorMessage="Required field." ValidationGroup="EditUserEmailValidation" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="message-error">
                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>            
                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="MaxValEditEmail" ControlToValidate="uigvTxtBoxEmail" runat="server"
                        ErrorMessage="Maximumn length is 80." ValidationGroup="EditUserEmailValidation" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="message-error"
                        ValidationExpression="^.{1,80}$" >
                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="uigvLblEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserEmail") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ShowHeader="False" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="uigvUpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" 
                                    Text="Update" CssClass="gridActionbutton"></asp:Button>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="uigvCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" 
                                    Text="Cancel" CssClass="gridActionbutton"></asp:Button>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="uigvEditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" 
                                Text="Edit" CssClass="gridActionbutton">
                    </asp:Button>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <RowStyle Wrap="True" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

When in edit mode if the field is left blank, both of the error messages are displayed.  If the user enters more than 80 characters, neither message is displayed.
I did this in an application using VS 2012.  Can this be done in VS2010?  If so, where am I going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use regularexpression validator or range validator instead of requiredfield validator for validating max length.

So you need to use one required field and the other is regular expression validator.

Comment: That was it!  Thanks.  My bad...I did too much cutting and pasting and not enough reading.

Comment: Both validations work the first time the 'Update' button is clicked. But if the user clicks it a second time, the validations are not triggered and the data is accepted.  How can I make sure the data is not accepted and the validations are triggered every time.